# SqlBulkCopy WriteToServerAsync using IDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, csvhelper, microsoft-data-sqlclient

I'm trying to use `SqlBulkCopy` to insert the contents of the CSV file into SQL Server Database from `IDataReader` (the specific implementation of the `IDataReader` is `CsvDataReader` from CsvHelper package). The following is my code:

```
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls, null))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
            bulkCopy.BatchSize = 4000;
            bulkCopy.EnableStreaming = true;
            await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dataReader, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

When trying to run this code I receive the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call ReadAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.
```

I believe this is the result of the fact that `IDataReader` doesn't have `ReadAsync` method

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: `WriteToServerAsync` has many overloads, so have you explored this idea? While `IDataReader` doesn't have a `ReadAsync` method, `DbDataReader` does. What is `dataReader`, can it be declared as a `DbDataReader` or one of its specific derived classes such as `SqlDataReader`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning `CsvDataReader` only implements `IDataReader` interface. I ended up writing a custom wrapper around `CsvReader` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a wrapper around `CsvReader`, that inherits from `DbDataReader`. I left most of the abstract method unimplemented, because I only needed a few methods for my purposes